# Convert mongo query to php syntax

Tags: php, mongodb

I need help to translate this query syntax in php. This query is just search for every text if it contains Hi, I need this code as it is. I know that in mongodb there is a different way to find strings but I NEED help to convert this query to php syntax. Any help

```
db.pos.find({ $where: function () { 
    var searchItem1 = /Hi/g; 
    for (var key in dataObj) { 
        var valueList = dataObj[key]; 
        if (searchItem1.test(valueList)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}})
```

Comment: Why you do not use `$regex` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) ?

Comment: I want to search the text keywords in order and the only way to check the order of the keywords is to right the $where function and after that query the database. for example if you have array [{"word":"I",pos:"V",index:1},{"word":"eat",pos:"V",index:2}] how to check the order according to index attribute? if the user enters "such things can" then how you can find those files which such is the first word after that things after that can. If you have an idea easy solution, please tell me

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.criteria.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but the results are necessarily to be in order which is a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`\MongoDB\BSON\Javascript`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-javascript.php) for that.

Code example:

```
$collection->find([
    '$where' => new Javascript('function () { 
        var searchItem1 = /Hi/g;
        for (var key in dataObj) { 
            var valueList = dataObj[key]; 
            if (searchItem1.test(valueList)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }')
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is it possible to take searchItem1 value from php form ??

Comment: @JehadAldahdooh yes, you can. Because we passing the JavaScript code as string. Example: `... var searchItem1 = /' . $searchItem . '/g; ...`

Comment: $js = 'function () {
  var dataObj = this.tokens; 
  var list = [];
  var querystring='.$querystring.';
     var check=[];
  var keyword = querystring.split(" ");........................}';

Comment: $querystring="word/I word/put"; from php side